# Different languages of site on different domains

Tags: wordpress, dns, multilingual

I have a site on WordPress with Polylang plugin for multi-language.
I want to set different language to different domains, for example:

http://english.com - for English

http://french.com - for french

It Will be nice to have one hosting account, but two domains. I think that I should pay attention to .htaccess and redirects.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

Polylang seems to support subdomains or domains per language.

You go to **Dasboard > Languages > Settings** and there, you have an option "*The language is set from different domain*s".

Here is an excerpt from the [documentation](https://polylang.pro/doc/url-modifications/#subdomains-name-and-domains) describing this option:

> it is possible to use subdomains (or a different domain per language).
>   All your subdomains (or domains) must point to the same directory
>   (where the WordPress index.php is present). Polylang checks if your
>   domains or subdomains are correctly accessible. Otherwise, Polylang
>   returns an error message.

And [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/polylang-was-unable-to-access-the-url/) you can find a discussion in WordPress support forum about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

For the exact same site content displayed in different languages, I don't think it's a good practice to use different domains for each language. As an eg, http://www.cbsrwstaging.com uses different languages, the language can be changed from the right top 'information' menu. For each different language it simply changes its URL, eg http://www.cbsrwstaging.com/de shows the site in german , http://www.cbsrwstaging.com/ja/ show the contents in Japanese etc. This site makes use of the WPML plugin.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Plugin that I already have installed (Polylang) make the same (lang switcher in a header), but I still finding approaches to implement multilang on a different domains.
I think, that it's a normal idea for promoting regional domains in a different geographical regions.

Comment: @СашкоЛисий if both the domains host the exact same content in different languages, then i dont think thats a good approach, its SEO scores might also get penalised for duplicate content. Alternatively, maybe you could use sub domains, eg `www.eng.domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with the subfolder solution as well. Also to keep the "strength" of the website at one .com domain and not multiple domains (or subdomains).

But both ways should be possible with one hosting account. Its more a question of the best solution for you.